# What is the source of an alternate quotation of "Execution of state criminals is both painful and unpleasant"?

Tags: star-trek

In Star Trek TOS "The Enterprise Incident" the Romulan commander states to Spock "Execution of state criminals is both painful and unpleasant."

This seemed like a redundant statement to me and possibly a misspoken like during filming.  I have seen the clip in a Star Trek made for TV special where she states the line differently and it is not redundant sounding.

Does anyone remember where this different clip was included?

Comment: I've seen most of the remastered episodes (including *The Enterprise Incident*, which I just reviewed). As far as I can tell, the remastered series tweaks the graphics and FX a bit without making any changes to the dialogue. A few minor usually-deleted scenes have been restored, and a few minor FX scenes added. Personally I find the remastered series quite an improvement, but that's IMHO. At any rate, the Romulan commander definitely says "painful and unpleasant" and her lips are in synch with those words, so I'm reasonably sure that's the original dialogue.

Comment: Well, maybe I just imagined the different dialogue, then. (Snort!)  "First thing that goes is your memory.  I don't remember what happens after that."

Answer (score 6):

I'm unaware of an alternative cut of the TV episode. Could you perhaps be confusing the [novelisation of the episode](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/76750.Star_Trek_4) by James Blish?

In it, he's changed the line to:

> "She was back in uniform now, and absolutely expressionless.
>   **“Execution for state criminals,” she said, “is both painful and demeaning.** I believe the details are unnecessary. The sentence will
>   be carried out immediately after charges are recorded.”

Comment: I thought I watched it on a made-for-TV show about Star Trek, hosted by William Shatner.  I also thought I had watched it on one of the time-travel episodes of DS9, but I looked them up and it wasn't there.